# Read line of numbers using C++

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream

What's the standard way of reading a "line of numbers" and store those numbers inside a vector.

```
file.in
12 
12 9 8 17 101 2
```

Should I read the file line by line, split the line with multiple numbers, and store the tokens in the array ?

What should I use for that ?

Comment: If you can guarantee they will be int's, you can simply read them and store them into an integer array (or an STL data structure like vector would work) granted that you explain how to parse with whatever delimiters you are using. If the output could be something else, you will probably want to read things into a string and use stringstream to convert them to integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> data;
std::ifstream file("numbers.txt");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(file), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(data));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream theStream("file.in"); 
    if( ! theStream )
          std::cerr << "file.in\n";
    while (true)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(theStream, line);
        if (line.empty())
            break;
        std::istringstream myStream( line );
        std::istream_iterator<int> begin(myStream), eof;
        std::vector<int> numbers(begin, eof);
        // process line however you need
        std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: The codes are beautiful! I have tested it and it works, but I don't understand one line (I am new to C++), could you please explain what does this line do? std::istream_iterator<int> begin(myStream), eof; Are begin and eof are two iterators? Thanks!

Comment: @ulyssis2: Yes, `begin` is an `istream_iterator` that will read from `myStream`, and `eof` is an `istream_iterator` that represents the end of the file.

Comment: thank you very much for answering me, I have a followup question, as eof is just declared and not initialized, how can it denote the end of the file?

Comment: `eof` is default initialized.  And the spec says that a default-initialized `istream_iterator` represents the end-of-stream iterator.

Comment: @HowardHinnant This answer really helped me in my project +1. Just wondering how to manipulate the numbers in detail. For instance, I'm not too sure how to access the 4th number on the second line ... or the nth number on the mth line of my file, from this solution. Regards

Answer (score 1):

std::cin is the most standard way to do this. std::cin eliminates all whitespaces within each number so you do

```
while(cin << yourinput)yourvector.push_back(yourinput)
```

and they will automatically be inserted to a vector :)

EDIT:

if you want to read from file, you can convert your std::cin so it reads automatically from a file with:

```
freopen("file.in", "r", stdin)
```

Comment: are you sure that `freopen` plays nice with `std::cin`?

Comment: I am pretty sure since no error comes to me until now.. except that freopen throws exception with the non existence of the file

Comment: Since when goes `freopen()` throw exceptions!?

Comment: `std::cin` does not eliminate the witespace, the `>>` operator does that. The pseudocode is wrong (why not just post real code?). Also reopening the standard input is not a good way to read files. Just use a `std::ifstream` and forget about `std::cin`.