# Reading Numbers from a File

Tags: c++, string, file, ifstream

I have a file with many numbers. The file looks like "192 158 100 0 20 200" basically like that. How can I load the files number values 1 at a time and display them on the screen in C++?

Comment: For a nice, fancy one-liner (at least for the reading and printing part), look up `std::copy`, `std::istream_iterator` and `std::ostream_iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
int val;
std::ifstream file("file");
while (file >> val)        
    std::cout << val;
```

Comment: will that read each number one by one? Or is that just printing the whole file to the screen?

Comment: oh I see. So it reads for example the number "142" as '1' '4' and '2'. Correct?

Comment: well, at every step val keeps full number. So, if file has "142 135 20" than val will have following values 142 135 20. But yes, in any way you will write this program the file will be internally read byte by byte.

Comment: a full number? okay what does this do? does it read a file that says "142 158 195" as "142" then resets and goes to "158" and then to "195" or does it go '1' '4' '2' and so on??

Comment: Okay, let me explain you. In line "file >> val" the program will cal operator>> of std::ifstream. This methods read file byte by byte (in other words digit by digit) until it meet a separator (in this case it is a space). To calculate the result the operator converts the read sequence of digits to integer variable. In next iteration it will start to at the same position.

Comment: @dvds414, It only reads a character when your `val` is a `char`. For ints, it's defined to read until a whitespace and store that number it read.

Comment: It is also wrong. The last number in the file will be printed twice. You should practically never use `while(EOF TEST)` as the EOF flag is only set after you read past the end of file and the last successfule read reads upto (but not past the EOF). The loop should be `while(file >> val)` this way the loop is onyl entered if the read was successful.

Comment: See LokiAstari's comment on my answer. This answer is no good.

Comment: Yeah, I made the same mistake. Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The following program should print each number, one per line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    int number;

    while (ifs >> number) {
       std::cout << number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fail: The last succeaaful read will not set the stream to bad. Thus you enter the while loop and `ifs >> number` may fail. The standard pattern is `while(ifs >> number)` thus if you fail the loop is not entered. Currently you will print the last value in the file twice.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following code:

```
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("text.txt");
    int output;
    if (myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        while (fs >> output) {   
            cout<<output;
        }
    }

//Of course closing the file at the end.
myReadFile.close();
```

As well, please include the iostream and fstream inside your code when using the example above.

Note that you need to start open a filestream to read and you can try to read it char by char and detect is there any white space in between it.

Good luck.

Comment: What exactly is this doing? My guess is that it's reading character by character? I can do that. I want to know how to read it number by number.

Comment: then you might want to take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005317/c-read-line-of-numbers

Comment: That is a fail. Practically never do while(EOF Test) it is nearly always wrong. The problem is that EOF is not true until you read past the EOF. Thus the last number will read upto (but not past the EOF). The read inside the loop will then and you will print the last value twice. What you should have done is while(fs >> v). Not this pattern is true for all languages not just C++.

Comment: See my comments about explicit use of close. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/540/507

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fs("yourfile.txt");
    if (!fs.is_open()) {
        return -1;
    }

    // collect values
    // std::vector<int> values;
    // while (!fs.eof()) {
    //    int v;
    //    fs >> v;
    //    values.push_back(v);
    // }
    int v;
    std::vector<int> values;
    while (fs >> v) {
        values.push_back(v);
    }
    fs.close();    

    // print it
    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a fail. Practically never do `while(EOF Test)` it is nearly always wrong. The problem is that EOF is not true until you read past the EOF. Thus the last number will read upto (but not past the EOF). The read inside the loop will then fail and you push a random value into `values`. What you should have done is `while(fs >> v)`. Not this pattern is true for all languages not just C++.

Comment: Note: Why not use the copy() to copy from the input to the output. There is no need for an intermediate store.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```
std::string filename = "yourfilename";

//If I remember well, in C++11 you don't need the
//conversion to C-style (char[]) string.
std::ifstream ifs( filename.c_str() );


//Can be replaced by ifs.good(). See below.
if( ifs ) {
    int value;

    //Read first before the loop so the value isn't processed
    //without being initialized if the file is empty.
    ifs >> value;

    //Can be replaced by while( ifs) but it's not obvious to everyone
    //that an std::istream is implicitly cast to a boolean.
    while( ifs.good() ) { 
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
        ifs >> value;       
    }
    ifs.close();
} else {
    //The file couldn't be opened.
}
```

The error-handling can be done in many ways through.

Comment: Works. But the standard pattern is: `while(ifs >> value)`. Which also makes the code more succinct. You are using `if (ifs)` but `while(ifs.good())` need to be consistent in usage. Personally I would not even test (unless you are reporting an error). No need for an explicit close RAII will close it correctly http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/540/507

Comment: @Loki Sorry for the lack of consistency, I changed the while at the last minute so I forgot the if. 
And thanks for the RAII tricks, I didn't knew that the destructor was closing the stream (which seems completly normal).