# Reading lines with 2 numbers each in C++

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream

I'm pretty rusty on my C++. I'm wondering what the best way is to read input in the following format:

```
400 200
138 493
...
```

I'm currently using `while(cin.peek()!=-1)` to check for EOF, and then within that, I'm using `while(cin.peek()!='\n')` to check for newlines. This is fine for reading in full lines of text, but how can I limit it to 2 numbers and/or grab just those 2 numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005317/c-read-line-of-numbers

Comment: `while (std::getline(std::cin, some_string)) { parse(line); }` and then you can parse the line by, for example, creating an `std::stringstream()` and extracting the numbers into two `int`s using `operator >>`.

Comment: Even though the other answer worked, I'm going to try this, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int num1,num2;
while(cin>>num1>>num2)
{
     //...
}
```

or

```
string line;
int num1,num2;
stringstream ss;
while(getline(cin,line))
{
    ss<<line;
    ss>>num1>>num2;
    //...
}
```

Comment: This does it, thanks. Though if I happen to try it with 3 numbers, it hangs waiting for a 4th. But I think the input I'm working with is guaranteed to be 2 numbers anyway.